# Want to show text and image from url in a textview no available examples are working

Tags: android, html, image, textview

I know this question already have lots of answer but nothing seems to work for me i don't know where i am wrong please have look on my below code.
I had used also lots of examples but nothing work for me.

```
     txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);

    String html = "Hello " +
            "<img src='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" +
            "f9dd8b16d54f483f22c0b7a7e3d840f9?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG'/>" +
            " This is a test " +
            "<img src='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a9317e7f0a78bb10a980cadd9dd035c9?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG'/>";
    spannedValue = Html.fromHtml(html,getImageHTML(),null);
    txt.setText(spannedValue);
```

This is my get Drawer method.

```
    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
    LevelListDrawable d = new LevelListDrawable();
    Drawable empty = 
    context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    d.addLevel(0, 0, empty);
    d.setBounds(0, 0, empty.getIntrinsicWidth(), 
    empty.getIntrinsicHeight());

    new LoadImage().execute(source, d);


    return null;
}
```

This is my Image loader class Where i also checked with hardcoded url also.

```
     class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Bitmap> {

    private LevelListDrawable mDrawable;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {
        String source = (String) params[0];
        mDrawable = (LevelListDrawable) params[1];
        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground " + source);
        try {

            URL url = new URL("https://www.gochatin.com/cdn/emoji/v1.0/assets/png/master/emoji_u1f601.png
");





            Log.d("url",url.toString());
            return 
          BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());

            /*InputStream is = new URL(source).openStream();
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);*/
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute drawable " + mDrawable);
        Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute bitmap " + bitmap);
        if (bitmap != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecuteafter" + bitmap);
            BitmapDrawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
            mDrawable.addLevel(1, 1, d);
            mDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 
            bitmap.getHeight());
            mDrawable.setLevel(1);
            // i don't know yet a better way to refresh TextView
            // mTv.invalidate() doesn't work as expected
            CharSequence t = txtMsg.getText();
            txtMsg.setText(t);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i fixed my issue .This is how i fixed.

```
     txtMsg.setText(Html.fromHtml(m.getMessage(),new ImageGetter(), null));
```

And below is my imagegetter method.

```
     public class ImageGetter implements Html.ImageGetter {

    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        int id;
        Log.d("source",source);


        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            bitmap = new LoadImage().execute(source).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Drawable d =new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);
        d.setBounds(0,0,d.getIntrinsicWidth(),d.getIntrinsicHeight());
        return d;
    }

}
```

This is my ImageLoader Class

```
     class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    private LevelListDrawable mDrawable;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {

            url=new URL(params[0]);
           // url = new URL("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a9317e7f0a78bb10a980cadd9dd035c9?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG");
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
           /* runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   // tasteimf.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    textviewt.setText(Html.fromHtml(html,new ImageGetter(), null));
                }
            });*/
            Log.d("image",bitmap.toString());
           // bitmap = Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a9317e7f0a78bb10a980cadd9dd035c9?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG").get();
            Log.d("bitmap",bitmap.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute drawable " + mDrawable);
        Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute bitmap " + bitmap);
        if (bitmap != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecuteafter" + bitmap);
           // myMethod(bitmap);

           CharSequence charSequence = textviewt.getText();
            textviewt.setText(charSequence);

        }

    }
}
```